# Replace outlier with last known value in R

Tags: r, outliers

Example Data:
2
4
6
10
99
150
14
15
45

Prior knowledge of the problem, I know that anything above 35 is an outlier but because the data depending on time, I would like to replace all value above 35 with the last known numbers that are under 35.  The dataset contains over millions of rows so I need to automatically do this instead of replacing one by one.

Result needed: 2 4 6 10 10 10 14 15 15

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- c(2, 4, 6, 10, 99, 150, 14, 15, 45)

#set outliers to NA
x[x > 35] <- NA

#fill NA values with Last Observation Carried Forward
library(zoo)
x <- na.locf(x)
#[1]  2  4  6 10 10 10 14 15 15
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that don't want a **zoo** package dependency, here's a simple version using run level encoding from base. The idea is simple, we just use the `rle()` and replace the `NA`s in the index with whatever is to the left (i.e. preceding value), and we skip any first `NA`s because there is no value to the left. Then we use `inverse.rle()` to get back to a full length vector. For reverse operation (, we just reverse the vector before and after. I haven't done benchmarking, but since all operations are vectorized, it should be quite fast.

`rle()` doesn't group `NA`s for some reason. Docs state "Missing values are regarded as unequal to the previous value, even if that is also missing.". Hence why I recode the `NA`s to a temporary string value, and have to convert the vector back to the right class. Not perfect, but works for most cases.

```
#' Last observation carried forward
#'
#' @param x A vector
#' @param reverse Whether to do it in reverse
#'
#' @return A vector
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA) %>% locf()
#' c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA) %>% locf(reverse = T)
locf = function(x, reverse = F) {
  #reverse?
  if (reverse) x = rev(x)

  #recode NA
  #these are kept distinct by rle() by default for same reason ???
  x_class = class(x)
  x[is.na(x)] = "___tmp"

  #run level encoding
  x_rle = rle(x)

  #swap values for NAs
  which_na = which(x_rle$values == "___tmp")

  #skip 1st
  which_na = setdiff(which_na, 1)

  #replace values
  x_rle$values[which_na] = x_rle$values[which_na - 1]

  #back to normal
  y = inverse.rle(x_rle)

  #NA recode
  y[y == "___tmp"] = NA

  #fix type/class
  if (x_class[1] == "logical") y = as.logical(y)
  if (x_class[1] == "integer") y = as.integer(y)
  if (x_class[1] == "numeric") y = as.double(y)
  if (x_class[1] == "factor") y = factor(y, levels = levels(x))
  if (x_class[1] == "ordered") y = ordered(y, levels = levels(x))

  #reverse?
  if (reverse) y = rev(y)

  y
}
```

Tests:

```
> c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA) %>% rle()
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
  values : num [1:5] NA 1 NA 2 NA
> c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA) %>% rle() %>% str()
List of 2
 $ lengths: int [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
 $ values : num [1:5] NA 1 NA 2 NA
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "rle"
> #swap the values for one to left
> #reverse rle
> c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA) %>% locf()
[1] NA  1  1  2  2
> c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA) %>% locf(reverse = T)
[1]  1  1  2  2 NA
> c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA) %>% locf()
[1] NA  1  1  2  2  2  2
```